# SharePoint workflow support?

Tags: workflow, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise + Publishing portal template + Windows Server 2008. I want to know any built-in types of workflow -- which  could be implemented by configuration without programming which is supported?

BTW: through tools like InfoPath are fine. I just want to save programming efforts to maintain code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the options for workflows in SharePoint 2007:

1. **Out-of-the-box**. These are described at [Office Online](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101544241033.aspx). They are limited in options but require no additional tools.
2. **SharePoint Designer**. These are a lot more flexible and created using a wizard interface within SPD. Here's a [video tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/In+the+Office/Creating-Custom-Workflows-with-the-SharePoint-Designer-2007/), and [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414204.aspx), you can search for many more resources.
3. **InfoPath Forms Server**. The next level up from SPD. Here is a resource to [get you started on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457061.aspx). Unlike SPD and out-of-the-box workflows, they are not bound to a specific list and can be redeployed to any list.
4. **Visual Studio**. The next level again but due to the additional complexity should probably be used only if you don't want to or can't use Forms Server for some reason. Strictly ASP.NET based. [Resource from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461324.aspx). As with InfoPath, can be redeployed to any list.

Here's an [overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms549489.aspx) of all of the options. You should start there to learn the pros and cons of each and how they work.

Comment: Cool, question answered!